# JTree with DefaultTreeModel, how to refresh visually after loading?

Tags: java, swing, model, jtree

I have been searching here and found answers to this problem but can't seem to make them work for me. Basicly I have a GUI that contains a JTree inside a JScrollPane:

```
private void initComponents() {

        scroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        nodo padre = new nodo();
        modeloArbol modelo = new modeloArbol(padre);
        arbol = new arbolNodos(modelo);
```

I have the following classes:

```
public class arbolNodos extends JTree implements Serializable{

    public arbolNodos(TreeModel newModel) {


public class listenerModeloArbol implements TreeModelListener{

//Overriding treeNodes*(TreeModelEvent e)


public class modeloArbol extends DefaultTreeModel implements Serializable{

    public modeloArbol(TreeNode root) {
        super(root);
    }


public class nodo extends DefaultMutableTreeNode implements Serializable{
```

I also have 2 buttons that store (botonGuardarArbol) and retrieve (botonCargarArbol) using the XMLEncoder the JTree (they really retrieve the root node of the tree) into a file with the corresponding actionPerformed listeners:

```
private void botonGuardarArbolActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
// TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\borrar\\presupuesto")));
        encoder.writeObject(arbol.getModel().getRoot());
        encoder.close();



private void botonCargarArbolActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
// TODO add your handling code here:    
    try {
        XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder( new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\borrar\\presupuesto")));

        nodo padre = (nodo) decoder.readObject();

        modeloArbol modelo = new modeloArbol(padre);

        decoder.close();

        modelo.setRoot(padre);

    arbolNodos arbolNuevo = null;

        if( modelo != null ){
            arbolNuevo = new arbolNodos(modelo);
            arbol = null;
            arbol = arbolNuevo;

            ((DefaultTreeModel)arbol.getModel()).reload();
        }
        else
            arbolNuevo = new arbolNodos();
```

The thing is, when I retrieve the stored JTree, I know it is well retrieved because I try printing attributes inside all the nodes of the Tree and they are ok, but when I try putting it up in the Swing it doesn't refresh and the view bloks (ie. I can't manipulate anything in the JTree I had before doing loading). I have tried the numerous threads of refresh/update JTree but couldn't fix it. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4):

```
if( modelo != null )
{
    arbolNuevo = new arbolNodos(modelo); // 
    arbol = null;
    arbol = arbolNuevo;
    ((DefaultTreeModel)arbol.getModel()).reload();
}         
else
    arbolNuevo = new arbolNodos();
```

Don't keep creating new JTree objects. If you want to change the model then just use:

```
tree.setModel(...);
```

Also, why are you extend JTree, DefaultTreeModel, DefaultMutableTreeNode? If for some reason you do need to extend those classes then follow standard Java naming conventions for those classes. Classes start with an upper case character.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'll also check the Java naming convention for classes... Thank you!